# What's wrong with this mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT v.*, COUNT(a.*) 
FROM vacancies AS v, applications AS a 
WHERE a.vacancy_id = v.id
```

Basically I need a way of counting the number of applications that correspond to each vacancy.

Applications have a vacancy id. So I want to get the vacancies from the `vacancies` table and iterate through them outputting the amount of applications that have the same vacancy_id.

Is this the right way to do it? It says I have a problem with the `COUNT(a.*)` bit.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Ok, so I tried the group by thing, and now have this:

```
SELECT v.*, COUNT(a.candidate_id)
FROM vacancies AS v, applications AS a 
WHERE a.vacancy_id=v.id 
GROUP BY v.title
```

But it only returns one result, because theres only one application. Is there any way to return EVERYTHING from the vacancies table, even if there are no applications associated with the vacancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNT is a group operation. You need to use GROUP BY at the end.

**EDIT**
Use left join

SELECT v.*, COUNT(a.candidate_id)
FROM vacancies AS v
LEFT JOIN applications AS a on a.vacancy_id=v.id 
GROUP BY v.title

Comment: Thank you for this. :) I've edited the question, I now have a problem with it won't select all vacancies, only those where there ARE applications associated with them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause. Add something like

```
   GROUP BY vacancy.somefield
```

to the query. See [COUNT function reference in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

To select all the members of the vacancies table, instead of writing

```
   WHERE a.vacancy_id = v.id
```

you should use a `LEFT JOIN` clause:

```
   LEFT JOIN applications ON a.vacancy_id = v.id
```

See the [MySQL JOIN documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. :) I've edited the question, I now have a problem with it won't select all vacancies, only those where there ARE applications associated with them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to GROUP BY something if you are mixing aggregate and names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    v.id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    vacancies AS v, 
    applications AS a 
WHERE 
    a.vacancy_id=v.id
GROUP BY 
    v.id
```

Comment: Thanks :) :) I've edited the question, I now have a problem with it won't select all vacancies, only those where there ARE applications associated with them. Any ideas?